# want to play audio and it should be stop after 10 seconds inHtml and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new  in Html5 and javascript I want to play audio clip when i open html page and it should be stop after 10 seconds and display message that Audio play successfully.

for simple audio play in html5 as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<audio controls>
  <source src="kill_bill.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<script>
setInterval(function(), 10000);

$.each($('audio'), function () { this.stop(); alert('Audio Stop Successfully'); });



</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A setTimeout seems more appropriate :

```
var audio = document.createElement("audio");
audio.src = "sound.mp3";

audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
        setTimeout(function(){
            audio.pause();
            alert("Audio Stop Successfully");
        },
        10000);
}, false);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tonyjahim/L6BCF/)

Comment: How we can pause the audio when for example 10 seconds left to end of audio?

Answer (score 1):

Put timer/counter on load of JS as it come to 10 seconds call the below function.

Timer
`setInterval(Call Below Function, 10000)`

Stop Audio
`$.each($('audio'), function () {
    this.stop();
    alert('Audio Stop Successfully');
});`

TRY THIS ::::

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>TIMER</title>  
</head>
<body>


<audio id="aud" controls autoplay>
  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>


<script type="text/javascript">
 var myaud = document.getElementById("aud");
 var k = setInterval("pauseAud()", 10000);

 function playAud() {
     myaud.play();
 }

 function pauseAud() {
     myaud.pause();
     alert('Audio Stop Successfully');
     clearInterval(k); 
 } 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: updated my question ,correct me if I am wrong ..This is my first program in Javascript.

Comment: ketan pls check my new question updated code it is not working where I am getting wrong ?

Comment: chk my this updated answer. and pls vote if ths has solved your question.

Comment: @dnana  **vote my answer if you solve your question** if u have any dought then feel free to tell me...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, pay attention: automatic play won't work under iOS; as Apple prevents it to be possible.

As for stopping audio, I always suggest to use [mediaelement](http://mediaelementjs.com/) library, which supports non HTML5 browsers and has a complete interface to start/stop audio playback.

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio id="audio_killbill" muted controls onload="audiofor_10sec()">
    <source src="kill_bill.mp3.mp3"></source>  <!-- Webkit Browser -->
    <source src="kill_bill.mp3.ogg"></source>  <!-- Mozilla/Firefox -->
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun <code>audio</code> time.
</audio>
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
function audiofor_10sec(){
     let audio = getElementById('audio_killbill');
     audio.muted = false; // New browser rule doesn't lets audio play automatically
     audio.play();         
     setTimeout(() => {
            audio.pause();
            audio.currentTime = 0; // Works as audio stop
     }, 10000);
 }
```